# Adding disk to windows-7 RAID-5

Tags: windows-7, software-raid

If I have a 3-disk RAID 5, and I want to add a 4th disk to the RAID, can this be done without moving all the data out of the existing raid array and rebuilding it as a 4 disk raid-5 array?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on who makes the RAID controller and what the model is, but I would be surprised if it didn't let you.

Note that if you add a disk to a RAID5 array, it must be equal or bigger in size than the smallest drive currently in the array.
You also need a free SATA port, but presumably, if you're asking about RAID, you know that already.

Comment: Hi, i am asking about windows (software) based RAID. I am familiar with how to set it up and the necessary software.